# pie setData animation HighCharts

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, pie-chart

I use pie chart of highcharts.
I have problem with animation when  try to set new Data.

```
      let chart = this.salesChart.getChart();
      chart.series[0].setData(this.state.salesData, true);
```

Can i with method setData  doing  animation

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/g9y428zu/

Comment: Please describe your problem.

Comment: my   data is dynamic  when i change select option  me  piechart have to  change data with animation.